# How to fix the Print Spool-service?

Tags: printer

I was trying to print a file and all of a sudden got the message:

[image]

Which basically says that he can't start the Print Spooler-service.

Any heads up on how to fix this?

I'm running Windows 7 with a Epson SX100 USB printer.

Comment: try manually starting it from services?

Comment: Go add that as an answer, since that was indeed the case. But please add some pics on how to do it @Mussnoon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here we go.

Go to start menu > run, and type in "services.msc" (or if you can't find "run" on the start menu, try pressing <kbd>R</kbd> while holding down the "Windows key"). When the services console appears, scroll down to "Print Spooler" and click the "Start Service" button on the toolbar (the one that looks like a "play" button from a media player).

[image]

Alternatively, you can start the task manager, switch to the "Services" tab, scroll down to "Spooler", right click on it, and click "Start service".

[image]

Comment: Awesome pictures @Mussnoon

Answer (score 2):

It's easy: open an elevated command prompt and type:

```
net start spooler
```